# Give an error before refreshing in ZF

Tags: php, zend-framework, prepared-statement, page-refresh

Hi i am new in Zend Framework. i am  working with existing project. 
Here,

```
$url = $this->view->url(array('controller' => $user->status), 'default', true);     
$url = $this->_getParam('url', $url);           
$this->_redirect($url);
```

it is redirected to another page but there i get following error:

```
Exception information:
Message: Mysqli statement execute error : No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement

Stack trace:

#0 C:\web\Apache2\php\Zend\1.11.3\library\Zend\Db\Statement.php(300): Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli->_execute(Array)
#1 C:\web\Apache2\php\Zend\1.11.3\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#2 C:\web\Apache2\php\Zend\1.11.3\library\Zend\Db\Table\Abstract.php(1526): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query(Object(Zend_Db_Table_Select))
#3 C:\web\Apache2\php\Zend\1.11.3\library\Zend\Db\Table\Abstract.php(1388): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->_fetch(Object(Zend_Db_Table_Select))
#4 C:\web\Apache2\htdocs\application\modules\default\controllers\generalController.php(24): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->fetchRow(Object(Zend_Db_Table_Select))
#5 C:\web\Apache2\php\Zend\1.11.3\library\Zend\Controller\Action.php(513): generalController->indexAction()
#6 C:\web\Apache2\php\Zend\1.11.3\library\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php(295): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('indexAction')
#7 C:\web\Apache2\php\Zend\1.11.3\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#8 C:\web\Apache2\php\Zend\1.11.3\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#9 C:\web\Apache2\php\Zend\1.11.3\library\Zend\Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#10 C:\web\Apache2\htdocs\public\index.php(59): Zend_Application->run()
#11 {main}
```

but if i refresh page everything get OK, i dont get error

i can not understand what is the problem
can anyone help me please?

Comment: Provide source code of a page you wanted to redirect.

Comment: This code does not cause error, give us code of $url page. This error has simple solution, you need to provide params for mysql prepared satement.

Comment: Provide code from `application\modules\default\controllers\generalController.php(24)` file

Comment: i found the reason. problem was with the server.it can't get data.Thanks you very much.